# Validation of HABTM association on delete:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a newbie rails question.  I'm trying to make sure a model has at least one association via a HABTM relationship.  Basically I have created the following validation:

```
validate :has_tags?
def has_tags?
    errors.add(:base, 'Must have at least one tag.') if self.tags.blank?
end
```

This works fine when I create a new record.  The problem is when I take the model and try to remove the association, doing something like this:

```
tag = Tag.find(params[:tag_id])$
@command.tags.delete(tag)$
```

It is permitted, i.e. the association will be deleted.  Based on my reading on HABTM associations (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association), I should "use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks, or extra attributes on the join model."

I guess my question is how to perform validation on the .delete method for an association.  Should I do this manually when I call delete (i.e. run a separate join to count the number of associations before executing a delete), or is there a way to use a validation model when deleting?  Here is my model:

```
class Command < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tagmapsorters
  has_many :tags, through: :tagmapsorters
  validates :text, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :text, uniqueness: true
  validate :has_tags?
  def has_tags?
    errors.add(:base, 'Must have at least one tag.') if self.tags.blank?
  end
end
```

I appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any callbacks that you need should be registered as `before_destroy` (for validations) or `after_destroy` (for cleanup) on the join model `Tagmapsorter`, as that is the record that is actually being destroyed.

Comment: This is correct. Thank you.  My problem was also that I was calling .delete through an association, i.e. @command.tags.delete(tag), instead of using .destroy, i.e. @command.tagmapsorters.find_by(tag_id: params[:tag_id]).destroy. delete doesn't trigger the callback.

Comment: @dps - just substitute `destroy` in place of `delete` (e.g. `@command.tags.destroy(tag)`).  You don't need to change your syntax otherwise.